# Registering / Enqueing Scripts Not Working

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

Does this look correct and would there be any reason why this isn't working?

In functions.php...

```
/**
* Enqueue scripts and styles
*/
function dcp_custom_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('expand', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/expand.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('expand');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dcp_custom_scripts' );
```

I've tried numerous variations from hundreds of articles online and nothing seems to work.

This is a modified off-the-shelf theme built by someone else. They have manually inserted all scripts and styles directly in the `<head>` so it's a bit of a mess.

Whatever I try, no scripts that I enqueue appear in the `<head>` at all, so it's not even attempting to work.

Comment: Are you sure the path to the js file is correct?

Comment: @Chittaranjan Yes, definitely correct - even if it wasn't though, it would still try to enqueue it and display in the `<head>` wouldn't it, but just 404...? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it will definitely include the file. If clicking the js file url in the browser source code gives you 404, then surely the file path is not correct. Please compare the path with your theme js file path and correct accordingly.

Comment: I've already said, the path is definitely correct... You completely misunderstood my last comment.

Comment: Then what's the meaning of 404 in your comment?

Comment: There is NOTHING in the `<head>` for the script I'm trying to enqueue. If there was, and I got the path to the js file wrong, then it would still be there, it would just 404. But it isn't, the enqueue is not working - it has nothing to do with an incorrect path to the js file as there is NOTHING in the `<head>` for the enqueued.

Answer (score 0):

On your header.php file, can you check if this function `<?php wp_head(); ?>` exists ? If not, then just add the code `<?php wp_head(); ?>` before the closing head tag `</head>`

Comment: No it doesn't - sorry I forgot to mention - the functions.php file includes `remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator'); ` (even with this commented out though, enqueuing still wasn't working). Thanks.